# T-SQL: CSV->table pipeline with custom parsed numeric data, lookup values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, import, csv, sql-clr

### **Problem**

Wish to insert thousands of records into a table `[Child]` from a CSV file (and do this from tens of files into the same table). However, I want to **A.** substitute a lookup value into the table (column values from `[Parent]`) and **B.** perform other computations on CSV-included data before the insert is made. How is this best accomplished?

The lookup is basically that I wish to return an `IDENTITY`-based primary key value (as `Child.P_ID`) from `[Parent]` where `[Parent].NVarCharValue,[Parent].DateTimeValue` match the first two fields from the CSV data, but I would rather not bother storing `NVarCharValue` and `DateTimeValue` themselves into `[Child]`, as future joins with other child-level tables will be on the `P_ID` field and this text info is redundant and would chew up space and perhaps cause additional lag time on insertions (although perhaps not as much as the lookups will be…but alas…).

For example of computationally-derived data (**B.**), I’d like to take encoded GPS coordinates in [d]ddmm.mmmm,C (Degrees*DecimalMinutes*,Direction) format and turn it into a single decimal degrees field (or half of a geography::Point). For example, my CSV contains such lovely entries as `3748.9729,S`, which should be parsed as 37° 48.9729’ S, then translate that to -37.816215 which would be stored for Latitude.

Options? I came up with 5 possibilities, but I don’t want to jump into coding any one of them unless I’ve considered all the pitfalls of an approach.

---

### **Option 1: Basic `Insert Into` view + `BULK INSERT`**

Even though I intend to only insert into the child table, the multi-table join needed to do the lookup probably violates the [MS constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/modify-data-through-a-view) on inserting a row into multiple underlying tables. It certainly would violate the [constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table) on no computations or aggregations specified in a `VIEW`’s DDL if inserting into that view.

Otherwise, this is (essentially) what I’d like to do

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ivChild] as 
SELECT 
  P.[ NVarCharValue],
  P.[ DateTimeValue],
  CAST(CAST((ABS(C.Latitude) as Integer) as VarChar(3))+STR(ABS(C.Latitude-CAST(C.Latitude as Integer))*60.0,9,6) as LatitudeMagnitude --not quite correct (single digit minutes), but close enough for the example
CASE
  WHEN SIGN(C.Latitude)>0 THEN ‘N’
  ELSE ‘S’
END as LatitudeDir,
CAST(CAST((ABS(C.Longitude) as Integer) as VarChar(3))+STR(ABS(C.Longitude-CAST(C.Longitude as Integer))*60.0,9,6) as LongitudeMagnitude
CASE
  WHEN SIGN(C.Latitude)>0 THEN ‘E’
  ELSE ‘W’
END as LongitudeDir
FROM Child as C join Parent as P on P.ID=C.P_id
```

But maybe I can have a subquery for the first two to have the insert take effect only on `Child`?
    e.g.

```
SELECT
  (SELECT P.NVarCharValue from Parent as P on P.ID=C.P_id) as NVarCharValue
  (SELECT P.DateTimeValue from Parent as P on P.ID=C.P_id) as DateTimeValue
    …
```

### **Option 2: `BULK INSERT` into Staging Table, Stored procedure `merge` into actual data table?**

Insert the `NVarCharValue` + `DateTimeValue` columns from the CSV into the staging table, then do either a `MERGE INTO` or `INSERT INTO` query to migrate the values to the data table, performing computations in-line (if possible) to perform the lookup and parse the string input values to final stored value (e.g. decimal degrees from string and then stored as decimal(10,6)).

### **Option 3: Create custom CLR for `GPSMagnitude`**

which would parse the incoming string in C#, store it internally to the class as a decimal number, and have an auto-convert to decimal datatype function. Something like

```
public static implicit operator Decimal(GPSMagnitude c) # GPS->decimal
    { return c._decimalMagnitude; }

Public static implicit operator GPSMagnitude(Decimal c) # decimal->GPS
    { return new GPSMagnitude(c); }
Public static implicit operator ToString(GPSMagnitude c)# GPS->string
    {
      d = (int)c;
      m = (c-(int)c)*60.0;
      return d.ToString()+m.ToString();
    }
[SqlMethod(OnNullCall = false)]
public GPSMagnitude Parse(SqlString s)           # string->GPS
    {
      Decimal f;
      int Deg;
      float Mn;
      Int32.TryParse(s, out f);
      Deg = ((int)f)/100
      Mn = f – Deg*100.0
      return new GPSMagnitude(Deg + Mn/60)
    }
```

Then use a view with `CAST(LatitudeMagnitude as GPSMagnitude)` specified and have an underlying table with `LatitudeMagnitude` specified as `decimal(10,6)`. I’d still have to do some funny business to get merge two columns to get the magnitude signed (S/W are negative), as well as I would have to independently deal with the P_ID lookup issue.

### Option 4: `BULK INSERT` with `FIRE_TRIGGERS`

Do the parsing in a custom trigger, which will take a string input and send it to the table as a decimal. Slows down BULK INSERT considerably from what I hear, but I should be able to both do a lookup and parse the GPS text. I haven’t given a whole lot of thought to what the TRIGGER code would be.

### Option 5: Pre-parse my CSV

in e.g. Python to do the GPS calculations, combining the magnitude and sign columns. I’d still have to deal with the P_ID lookup issue though

### Option 6: Your solution to my ugly input dataset.

I can flesh out more of these options if you're confused by what I have:P

---

Based on Solomon's suggestion, I'm beginning to implement a C# stream-parser.

To grab the existing structure off a table, the following code should work (with a few tweaks possibly). Note that this uses `else ifs` rather than `switch case` as it seems more code-compact (not so many break statements needed, etc). I'm not sure which would be more efficient.  I also haven't grabbed of all the columns to cover all contingencies, but for the most basic types it should work okay. Again...this is just for approximating the table fields you already have set up in SQL server.

```
    public SqlMetaData[] ServerLookupFields()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ParserDict.ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command;
            int siz;
            Console.WriteLine("Activating SQL connection");
            conn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("SQL connection open");
            string num = "select count(*) as cnt from sys.columns as sc join sys.tables as st on sc.object_id = st.object_id where st.name=@table_name;";
            command = new SqlCommand(num, conn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table_name", this.tableDestination);
            string result = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            Int32.TryParse(result, out siz);
            command.Dispose();
            SqlMetaData[] smd = new SqlMetaData[siz];
            string cmd = "exec sp_columns @table_name=@table_name, @table_owner=dbo";
            command = new SqlCommand(cmd, conn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table_name", this.tableDestination);
            SqlDataReader rd = command.ExecuteReader();
            int i = 0;
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                smd[i] = ReadSingleMetaRow((IDataRecord)rd);
                Console.WriteLine(smd[i].Name.ToString()+","+smd[i].DbType.ToString());
                i++;
            }
            rd.Close();
            command.Dispose();
            return smd;
        }
    }
    private SqlMetaData ReadSingleMetaRow(IDataRecord meta)
    {
        bool nullable;
        byte precision;
        byte length;
        byte scale;
        SqlMetaData smd;
        string columnName = meta[3].ToString(); //Column_name
        string dataType = meta[5].ToString(); //Type_name
        string dt_fw_lower = dataType.ToLower().Split(new Char[] { ' ' }, 2)[0]; //dataType_firstWord_ToLower
        byte.TryParse(meta[6].ToString(), out precision); //Precision
        byte.TryParse(meta[7].ToString(), out length); //Length
        byte.TryParse(meta[8].ToString(), out scale); //Scale
        Boolean.TryParse(meta[10].ToString(), out nullable); //Nullable
        string datetimesub = meta[14].ToString(); //DateTimeSub(type)
        if (dt_fw_lower == "datetime2") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.DateTime2); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "nvarchar") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.NVarChar, length); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "varchar") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.VarChar, length); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "bigint") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.BigInt); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "float") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.Float, precision, length); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "decimal") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.Decimal, precision, scale); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "binary") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.Binary, length); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "varbinary") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.VarBinary, length); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "bit") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.Bit); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "char") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.Char, length); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "nchar") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.NChar, length); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "datetimeoffset") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "datetime") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.DateTime); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "date") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.Date, length); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "image") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.Image, length); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "int") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.Int); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "money") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.Money, length); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "ntext") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.NText, length); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "real") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.Real, precision, scale); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "smalldatetime") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.SmallDateTime); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "smallint") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.SmallInt); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "smallmoney") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.SmallMoney); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "structured") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.Structured, length); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "text") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.Text, -1); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "timestamp") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.Timestamp); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "time") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.Time); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "tinyint") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.TinyInt); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "udt") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.Udt, length); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "uniqueidentifier") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, length); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "variant") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.Variant, length); }
        else if (dt_fw_lower == "xml") { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.Xml, length); }
        else { smd = new SqlMetaData(columnName, 0); }
        return smd;
    }
```

Comment: We use Option 2 for loading into our data warehouse. We populate a Staging table; then populate several dimension tables (similar to parent); then populate fact tables by looking up the IDs from the dimension tables. It's fast enough for us. As far as the parsing is concerned, I think that CLR or pre-processing would be best. String parsing isn't SQL Server's strong suit.

Comment: I have an Option 6 posted in at least one other answer on here..I will try to find it and post the link here..

Comment: I would use PowerShell to read CSV files and then dump into target sql table. But if you provide a piece of real CSV data and a simple parent (child) table structure, it would be easier for people to come up with real code for you.

Comment: For the `SqlParameter`s, you shouldn't use `AddWithValue` as you can run into problems with that method. Is best to create it with a specific datatype. Also, I don't think that `date` should come before `datetimeoffset` and `datetime`. Why apply the `ToLower()` per each `if`? Won't that run the same operation 30 or so times if the type is `xml`? It can be done once when you get it from `meta[5]`, right? Finally, why bother with `StartsWith()` anyway instead of switching on the actual `name.ToLower()`? That is what I have always done and haven't run into any problems (yet ;-).

Comment: If the `StartsWith()` is due to trailing spaces then you can use `Trim()`, or better yet, get rid of `sp_columns`. Personally, I would never use any of those provided `sp_*` procs (e.g. `sp_tables`, etc.). A lot of them format the output to look nice as a report, or possible from **SQLCMD**. Either way, you are better off not using them. If there is a JOIN that you can't seem to figure out, look at the body of it via `EXEC sp_helptext 'sp_columns'`. Take what you need and write a simple query to get just what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do this in pieces. You can do all of this inline, in a set-based approach, in batches (so that the size of the input file is irrelevant). Just think in terms of how you would take a row from the file and process it from start to finish. Then, make sure that each step is operating on a set of rows instead of a single row.

This won't require any SQLCLR, but will use either XML or a Table-Valued Parameter (TVP) to transport the batch of rows to SQL Server *after* it has been processed locally.

The basic workflow is as follows (I have this documented in another answer but can't find it at the moment). It requires a User-Defined Table Type be created to transport each row to the Stored Procedure (this is the TVP and is available as of SQL Server 2008, which you have).

1. Open the file
2. Loop over N rows (a batch) until no rows left

   1. Perform validations
   2. Convert encoded GPS coordinates to decimal format
   3. Send the row (using a method that implements `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`, *not* a `DataTable` !) to the stored procedure:

      1. create a local temporary table with the TVP columns *plus* columns to hold any generated `IDENTITY` values.
      2. populate the temp table from the TVP
      3. Insert into `[Parent]` where `[Parent].NVarCharValue` and `[Parent].DateTimeValue` do not exist. You can either capture `IDENTITY` values along with `[Parent].NVarCharValue` and `[Parent].DateTimeValue` into another temp table to then update the main temp table with so that it can get the new IDENTITY values, or you might be able to skip that and just JOIN to the `[Parent]` table when doing the final `INSERT`.
      4. If you captured new IDENTITY values for `[Parent]` into a second temp table, UPDATE the main temp table with those values, matching on `NVarCharValue` and `DateTimeValue`.
      5. If appropriate, `UPDATE` the `[Child]` table from the main temp table, JOINing on one or more columns that uniquely identify the rows (i.e. an Alternate Key). This is effectively a `WHERE EXISTS`.
      6. `INSERT INTO [Child]` from the main temp table, using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` on whatever column(s) uniquely identify the rows
3. Close the file

I have used this approach several times and with great success. It is fault-tolerant so it will easily resume where it left off if interrupted. And, it doesn't require any staging tables (which need to be cleaned out and get messy if you are multi-threading the import) as the local temporary table plays that role and is automatically cleaned up *and* is inherently thread-safe :-). This also lets you process pieces in the app layer that are most appropriate to handle there, and process the rest in the data layer. AND, as far as memory is concerned, you only ever have 1 batch worth of import file in memory at any given time, so it won't matter if the import file is 10 kB or 10 GB.

Also, you *can* get fancier with the process on the DB side if you like. I typically have a status column to determine: Insert, Update, or Skip. Then, after populating the main temp table, I compare to the existing destination table. If the row is there but one or more columns are different, it gets marked as Update. If the row is there but all columns are the same, it gets marked as Skip (no need to UPDATE rows that aren't changing). Else, it gets marked as Insert. Then, at the end, I `UPDATE` where Status = Update, then I `INSERT` where Status = Insert. Of course, I was importing into several tables that each had their own "funky" rules ;-).

You can see some sample code in another answer of mine on Stack Overflow:
[How can I insert 10 million records in the shortest time possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25773471/577765) Please note that the structure of that code is *not* batched. It executes the stored procedure once, which initiates the process of opening the file, reading and sending rows, and finally closing. In order to make it batched, you would need to change it to be something along the lines of:

1. Open file
2. while (! file.EOF)

   1. execute Stored Procedure: "SendRows" method has input parameter for file handle

      1. "SendRows" method =
      2. while ( rowCount < batchSize ) // this is the "Loop over N rows" part of the workflow

         1. file.ReadLine()
         2. if ( file.EOF ) `break;`
         3. process and send row // Perform validations, Convert encoded GPS coordinates
         4. `rowCount++;`
3. Close file

Comment: Possibly dumb question: is there a way to fill the SqlMetaData structure from an existing table via an SQL query?

Comment: Possibly answering own question: this looks promising - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19392916/4228193

Comment: Not sure `GetSchema()` would work for a TVP since they are a User-Defined Table Type, not a regular Table. But I suppose you could query the relevant system catalog views to get that info.

Comment: You will need to query `sys.table_types` and `sys.columns` at the very least.

Comment: any clue what to do here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47947871/mismatch-in-net-metadata-for-sql-datetime-type